# Send sniffed ESP packet with Scapy

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, sniffing, ipsec

I'm trying to pentest an `IPSEC` implementation with no Auth in `Tunnel mode` for a Uni Project.
After sniffing an ESP packet (which contains an ICMP) with `Wireshark`, the attacker sends the same packet with `Scapy` to `Host A`. The problem is that the `Router A` do not forward anything to his `Host A`.

I am also using Scapy with the ESP implementation from https://github.com/secdev/scapy

This is My Configuration:

```
HOST A: 10.0.1.10

ROUTER A NIC-1: 10.0.1.24
ROUTER A NIC-2: 192.168.100.1

HOST B: 10.0.2.10

ROUTER B NIC-1: 10.0.2.24
ROUTER B NIC-2: 192.168.100.2

ATTACKER: 192.168.100.3
```

after I use `sendp` from the `ATTACKER` machine, i see the `ESP` packet on `Router A`

```
06:03:03.088236 IP 192.168.100.2 > Tirith: ESP(spi=0xc18c8ed9,seq=0x1b), length 120
```

sadly, it doesn't happen anything on HOST A.

I can do the same thing without the `ESP`,with a simple ICMP packet,  everything works: `Router A` gets the packet and forward to `HOST A`, so it seems that the interface is also set correctly.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does Router A use replay protection? Did you change the sequence number? The latter will only work if there really is no integrity protection (although ESP without it is rarely used, if at all).

Comment: Yeah it was the replay protection that I forgot, I have momentarily deactivated and it works. Now I have to figure how to change it with Scapy. That's what I'm trying to achieve by the way: A Denial-of-Service attack on a host behind a IPSEC gateway without integrity protection, to prove the vulnerability of encryption-only protocols.